# Editable drop-down list with datalist not showing options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I got 2 examples. One static that works fine and the values show up correctly in the datalist during runtime. The other dynamically example the values does not appear at all in the datalist during runtime. I have made them as identically as I can.

Working example, JS:

```js
var thisListShowsUp     = ['Value1','Value2'];
var listToShow          = view.$el.find('[data-id="listToShow"]');
var thisListDoNotShowUp = []

//fetchedItemFromDBList gets populated from get request from DB. See log
fetchedItemFromDBList.forEach(function(item)
  {
  thisListDoNotShowUp.push(item.stringValue);
  });

console.log(thisListDoNotShowUp);
console.log(thisListShowsUp);

thisListShowsUp.forEach(function(item)
  {
  var option       = document.createElement('option');
  var stringValue  = item.toString();
  option.value     = stringValue
  listToShow.append(option);
  });
```

Not working example, JS:

```js
var thisListShowsUp     = ['Value1','Value2'];
var listToShow          = view.$el.find('[data-id="listToShow"]');
var thisListDoNotShowUp = []

//fetchedItemFromDBList gets populated from get request from DB. See log
fetchedItemFromDBList.forEach(function(item)
  {
  thisListDoNotShowUp.push(item.stringValue);
  });

console.log(thisListDoNotShowUp);
console.log(thisListShowsUp);

thisListDoNotShowUp.forEach(function(item)
  {
  var option      = document.createElement('option');
  var stringValue = item.toString();
  option.value    = stringValue

  listToShow.append(option);
   });
```

HTML:

```
<input name="test" list="listToShow" />
<datalist id="listToShow" data-id="listToShow"></datalist>
```

log:

```
["foo1", "bar1"]
["Value1", "Value2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a constructor to create an option : [new Option()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)
You also need to [use a set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to avoid duplicates

your code could be:

```js
const 
  displayThis = new Set(['value1','value2'])   // added values
, listToShow  = document.querySelector('datalist[data-id="listToShow"]')
, fetchedItemFromDBList =
  [ { stringValue: 'foo1' }
  , { stringValue: 'bar1' }
  ]

fetchedItemFromDBList.forEach( item => displayThis.add( item.stringValue ))

displayThis.forEach( item => listToShow.appendChild(new Option('', item )))
```

```html
<input name="test" list="listToShow" />
<datalist id="listToShow" data-id="listToShow"></datalist>
```

Comment: Same result. Still no visible options to choose from. If i log the datalist to console , the innerHTML seems correct:
innerHTML: "<option value="foo1"></option><option value="bar1"></option>"

Comment: I tried doing this:
               var displayThis = [ 'foo1', 'bar1']                  
               fetchedItemFromDBList.forEach(function(item){

                      displayThis .push(item.stringValue)

                  });
          
                  console.log(displayThis );

                  var listToShow = view.$el.find('[data-id="listToShow"]');

                 displayThis .forEach(function(item){

                  listToShow.append(new Option('', item ))

                  });

Now only "foo1" and "bar1" is visible in the list. All the values is logged

Comment: @SebasJun  `fetchedItemFromDBList` already contain your `displayThis` values